# How to code pop-up annotations like Rap Genius?

Tags: html, css, web

I'm creating a section on my personal site where I want certain elements to be highlighted and clickable. When someone clicks it, it opens an annotation with descriptions or images or other embeds, just like [the lyrics on Genius.com](http://genius.com/6606430).

I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS so I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Any insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Try and learn about HTML/CSS and share a working piece of code. This forum will provide all necessary help then.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way they do it on that website is by creating divs that are either hidden or pushed off the screen upon load. And when the user clicks on a certain section of the lyrics, it triggers an onclick which will call javascript functions to slide the hidden div back into view.